# At which point in the lifecycle does GetConnectionInterface get called?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts, page-lifecycle, webpart-connection

I have this method on a webpart:

```
private IFilterData _filterData = null;

[ConnectionConsumer("Filter Data Consumer")]
public void GetConnectionInterface(IFilterData filterData)
{
    _filterData = filterData;
}
```

Now, before I can call upon `_filterData`, I need to know when i can expect it to not be *null*.  When is this?!

Without knowing this, the best I can do is stuff all of my `_filterWebpart` dependent code into the last lines of `OnPreRender` and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this document, it looks like Load.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366536.aspx